# Multivalued hierarchal xml tag

Tags: python, xml

I have a piece of text with many classifications and I'm thinking of a perfect design for classification xml tag.

so for example, text id="1"has 2 classifications, each in tree structure:

```
class1
 class2
   class3
```

another classification:

```
class1
  class6
    class10
```

First xml design:

```
<class tree="class1;class2;class3"\>
<class tree="class1;class6;class10"\>
  <text id="1">
     here the text
  </text>
```

Another design is

```
<class1>
   <class2>
      <class3>
      </class3>
   </class2>
</class1>
<class1>
   <class6>
      <class10>
      </class10>
   </class6>
</class1>
  <text id="1">
     here the text
  </text>
```

Which one do you think is appropriate?, I want to be able to retrieve all text belong to one class.

Any suggestions are welcome..

Comment: I would say go with the last one. But thats just what I think.

Comment: thank you Games for your comment, but why do you think this design is suitable?

Comment: Because its the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the 3rd design, because its the cleanest and easiest to read. Parsing would be simpler in my opinion as well. You could do it all using very simple regular expressions.